# Error in copying file from k8s pod to local

Tags: kubernetes

I used this command `kubectl cp <some-namespace>/<some-pod>:/tmp/foo /tmp/bar`

Got error `error: serializer for text/html; charset=utf-8 doesn't exist`

Didn't find a solution for it. Is it something to set in kube config?
Other things with the kubectl are fine.

Maybe because I used a permission limited path as target

Comment: That error suggests that your kubernetes server is not returning expected information: you're getting an HTML error message rather than the expected JSON reply. Try connecting to the API endpoint in your browser and see what it says, maybe?

Comment: @larsks Tried, it returns a json

Comment: does this file exist ~/.kube/config ? if so, the server is it pointing to the correct IP for the kube api server ?

Comment: also try something dummy, do you get the same error if you run: kubectl get nodes